# CanCan ability ignores a condition that should disallow access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancan, cancancan

In `ability.rb`

```rb
can :edit, Physician, user_id: user.id
```

If my understanding is correct, this should look at the instance of physician in the controller, take its `user_id` attribute, and only allow access when it matches the current user id.

Instead, **anyone can access anyone else's `edit` action! (bad)**

#### What I think's happening

I have a custom route for the edit action:

```
get 'physicians/:physicianname/edit' => 'physicians#edit'
```

And in the edit controller:

```
@physician = Physician.find_by(physicianname: params[:physicianname])
```

Since I'm not looking up the physician in the usual way (using an :id), I think some of the cancan magic/defaults aren't applying as they should be.

But I cannot figure out why, or what I have to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you miss the check that should raise the unauthorized response. In your action, you should have something like this:

```rb
  @physician = Physician.find_by(physicianname: params[:physicianname])
  authorize! :edit, @physician
```

Take a look at the [gem wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions)